# Getting a shell error code from curl in Jenkins while still displaying output in console

Tags: bash, curl, jenkins, tee

I am using a shell script in Jenkins that, at a certain point, uploads a file to a server using curl. I would like to see whatever output curl produces but also check whether it is the output I expect. If it isn't, then I want to set the shell error code to > 0 so that Jenkins knows the script failed.

I first tried using `curl -f`, but this causes the pipe to be cut as soon as the upload fails and the error output never gets to the client. Then I tried something like this:

```
curl ...params... | tee /dev/tty | \
  xargs -I{} test "Expected output string" = '{}'
```

This works from a normal SSH shell but in the Jenkins console output I see:

```
tee: /dev/tty: No such device or address
```

I'm not sure why this is since I thought Jenkins was communicating with the slave using a normal SSH shell. In any case, the whole xargs + test thing strikes me as a bit of a hack.

Is there a way to accomplish this in Jenkins so that I can see the output and also test whether it matches a specific string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Jenkins communicates with slave via SSH, there is no terminal allocated, and so there is no `/dev/tty` device for that process.

Maybe you can send it to `/dev/stderr` instead? It will be a terminal in an interactive session and some log file in non-interactive session.

Comment: I still don't understand why /dev/stdout doesn't work, but thanks, /dev/stderr works fine and writes to the Jenkins console.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using the [Publish over SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) instead of using curl? Might save you some headache.

If you just copy the file from master to slave there is also a plugin for that, [copy to slave Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin).

Cannot write any comments yet, so I had to post it as an answer.

Comment: I can't publish via SSH but if there's a way to do it as an HTTP POST then that might be an interesting alternative. I took a look at the Jenkins plugin list but nothing jumped out at me.